BPHZ renormalization and the minimal subtraction scheme
I am trying to understand the role of the minimal subtraction scheme in the context of renormalization of quantum field theories.
In particular I work in dimensional regularization using the BPHZ algorithm.
Working at 1 loop I have the 1 loop lagrangian $\mathcal{L}^{(1)}=\mathcal{L}+\Delta \mathcal{L}^{(1)}$, where $\Delta \mathcal{L}^{(1)}$ contains the 1 loop counterterms; At two loops I consider Feynman rules coming from the 1 loop lagrangian $\mathcal{L}^{(1)}$, these produce some divergent diagrams at 2 loops that will sum with the "genuine 2 loops diagrams" giving a 2 loop divergence that I need to cancel by adding the 2 loops counterterms.
For example if I work with the theory $\lambda\phi^4$ in D=4 I know that the 2 loops divergence for the 4 point amputed function is (when i sum all the diagrams at two loops, obtained by using 1 loop Feynman rules):
$$ \frac{\lambda^3}{(2\pi)^4} (K^2)^\epsilon (\frac{1}{\epsilon^2}+\frac{1}{\epsilon }N)+finite \hspace{2cm}(1)$$
In order to cancel the divergence I add the 2 loops counterterm lagrangian:
$$\Delta \mathcal{L}^{(2)} = [\frac{\lambda^3}{(2\pi)^4} (K^2)^\epsilon (\frac{1}{\epsilon^2}+\frac{1}{\epsilon }N)+finite]\phi^4 \hspace{2cm}(2)$$
such that the sum of all diagrams at two loops gives a finite contribution (everything is finite at 2 loops).
Note that N is a finite part which does not depend on $p^2$ and in my notation $D=4-2\epsilon$.
If i follow the same argument for the 2 point function i find that the sum of all 2 loop diagrams that comes from the 1 loop lagrangian is:
$$\frac{\lambda^2 p^2}{24(2\pi)^4 \epsilon}+\frac{\lambda^2m^2}{2(2\pi)^2}(\frac{1}{\epsilon^2}+\frac{1}{2\epsilon}(F_1+3G_1+1)+finite)\hspace{2cm}(3)$$
where $F_1$ and $G_1$ are the finite parts of the 1 loop 2 and 4 point functions respectively which depend on the particular subtraction scheme.
The same is for the 4 point function above.
If I work in the minimal sub. scheme, I want counterterms to contain only the divergent parts of the diagrams.
As it seems to me if I choose a subtraction scheme I have to stick to it at any order in loops; this means that I will choose the counterterms at 1 loop to not contain any finite part, which would make disappear the scheme dependent parts proportional to the $\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ term in equation 3, such that the counterterms that I will add at 2 loops will not contain any scheme dependence at all; again at two loops I will find a finite part which depends on the scheme, but I will choose 2 loops counterterms to contain only the divergent part, which in turn is universal, and so on for higher orders.
Is this right ? is it true at any order in loops I will find divergent parts that does not contain any scale/scheme dependence, not only in the higher order poles but also in the lower poles?
Moreover, in the context of the RG, if We obtain RG equations using the dimensional approach we will HAVE TO work in the minimal sub. scheme, indeed if We do not do so we will find renormalized quantities that depends on the scheme, which in turns make the equations impossible (or at least very difficult) to solve.
This is a reason to think that I can always find a way to work in the minimal sub. scheme at any order in loops, which implies not having any scheme dependence in counterterms.

Choosing a scheme to remove scheme-dependent terms seems a bit circular doesn't it :) I didn't follow all the details but being careful about consistently defining your scheme makes sense, but I don't think it strictly makes sense to say you are removing scheme dependent terms (you are just choosing a scheme where these terms are zero, and zero is a scheme-dependent value). Apologies if this is just nitpicking and not useful.

As i understood if i choose the min. sub. scheme i am deciding to subtract only the divergent part of green functions, such that the functions $Z_\phi,Z_\lambda Z_m$ do not depend on the scheme. In this case renormalized $\lambda, m, \phi$ do not depend on the scale K and the finite part remains in the expression of renormalized green functions. What is not clear to me is if at any order in loop i am always left with a divergent part (which can be a sum of  of powers of $1/\epsilon$ with coefficients) that do not depend on the scheme (and so on the scale).  is this a general L-loop pattern ?
